# How to make my retrieved values into pages SQL

Tags: php, sql

I have information stored in MySQL database, and its more than 1000 row, I need to make pages for results, for every page 50 results, how can I make something like that ?

Comment: What have you read about that could help you?

Comment: http://www.phpbuilder.com/columns/rod20000221.php3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read:

- http://www.9lessons.info/2009/09/pagination-with-jquery-mysql-and-php.html (jQuery)
- http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/29.html

Comment: Really thanks to all people here, I was wrong in making links for Next and Prev my code was not right, thank you you solve my problem,BTW the Jquery is cool.